# Python groupby and count to show on the plot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python

Kindly request to help to write this correctly. On the picture I have a table with "Team" and "Points". I would like to count how many points each F1 Team have gathered to show it on the plot. I was trying to do it like that:

```
team_points= cons.groupby('Team')['Points'].count()
team_points = pd.DataFrame(team_points)
team_points.columns = ['Points']
team_points.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

team_points.sort_values(by=['Points'], inplace=True, 
ascending=False)
team_points = team_points.head(10)
team_points = team_points[::-1]

fig = px.bar(team_points, x='Team', 
y='Points',color='Points',width=750, height=500)
fig.update_layout(title={'text': 'Teams with The Most Championships 
Won','y':0.95,'x':0.5})
fig.show()
```

Table

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **pandas** code is doing quite odd things

- ensure **points** is numeric
- `groupby().agg()` to get the total
- have filtered to teams that have more that 100 points to limit number of bars
- **plotly** code is then simple

```
import plotly.express as px
import requests
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/constructorStandings.json", params={"limit":1000})
df = (pd.DataFrame(res.json()["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"])
 .explode("ConstructorStandings").reset_index(drop=True)
 .pipe(lambda d: d.loc[:,["season","round"]].join(d["ConstructorStandings"].apply(pd.Series)))
 .pipe(lambda d: d.join(d["Constructor"].apply(pd.Series))).drop(columns="Constructor")
)
df["points"] = pd.to_numeric(df["points"])

dfp = df.groupby(["name"]).agg({"points":"sum"}).loc[lambda d: d["points"].gt(100)]

px.bar(dfp, x=dfp.index, y="points", color="points")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help! I am a still a beginner, could you please meybe suggest some learning sources? I am now using Data Camp, Kaggle and Coursera

Comment: SO is another good way to learn.  try finding solutions to questions and you will also learn from other answers